# c# -- How can I make a microsecond timer?

Tags: c#, timer

Can anyone help me?
How can I make a microsecond timer in c#?
Like other timers, I want to do Something in the timer body.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Try searching first: https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=microsecond%20timer%20c%23 First result looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with Stopwatches setting the tick-frequency to micoseconds via:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L*1000L));
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: This makes sense to me, however it's not working -- it's giving me error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 3):

Here you can download MicroLibrary.cs:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98346/Microsecond-and-Millisecond-NET-Timer
Example for your problem:

```
    private int counter = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();

        program.MicroTimerTest();



    }



    private void MicroTimerTest()
    {

        MicroLibrary.MicroTimer microTimer = new MicroLibrary.MicroTimer();
        microTimer.MicroTimerElapsed +=
            new MicroLibrary.MicroTimer.MicroTimerElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        microTimer.Interval = 1000; // Call micro timer every 1000µs (1ms)
        microTimer.Enabled = true; // Start timer

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //do smth 2 seconds

        microTimer.Enabled = false; // Stop timer (executes asynchronously)

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender,
                            MicroLibrary.MicroTimerEventArgs timerEventArgs)
    {
        // Do something every ms
        Console.WriteLine(++counter);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It generally works for my purpose, but there is some strange behavior. If you put Console.Writeline (DateTime.Now.Milliseconds) in the OnTimedEvent function, you would expect one line per millisecond and it happens that multiple lines are written in the same millisecond. Why is that happening?

Comment: @A.Dzebo It simply because callback function takes too long then next callbacks are pilling up and fire up in the same millisecond  to make up for being late, thus we have milisecond value in the couple of lines.
From docs of this library:"By design, the amount of work done in the callback function (OnTimedEvent) must be small (e.g. update a variable or fire off a UDP packet). To that end, the work done in the callback function must take significantly less time than the timer interval"

Comment: @A.Dzebo You can type this code for clarification in the callback function, using the event arguments from library.
`Console.WriteLine("callback time:\t" + timerEventArgs.CallbackFunctionExecutionTime + "\ttimerLateBy:\t" + timerEventArgs.TimerLateBy +  "\tdatetime miliseconds:\t" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond + "\tand counter\t" + ++counter);`
Couple observations worth noting that using DateTime.Now before starting timer makes initial duplicates less to happen also DateTime.NowUtc works better in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am running the embedded code in a separate thread and I expect this timer not to depend on what is happening inside the OnTick function. I expect it to start exactly every 200 microseconds (if this is set as an interval). Otherwise I cannot rely on this timer.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.spinwait?view=netframework-4.8)

is also essential for implementing this 'MicroTimer' lo-level class purpose.